# run-sml does not work in emacs sml-mode

Tags: emacs, polyml, sml-mode

I want to use sml-mode in emacs on Fedora. My `~/.emacs` file contains

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/gbuday/prooftheory/sml-mode")
(autoload 'sml-mode "sml-mode" "Major mode for editing SML." t)
(autoload 'run-sml "sml-proc" "Run an inferior SML process." t)
```

where that directory contains the git-cloned sml-mode files.

I edited `sml-mode.el` to have

```
(defcustom sml-program-name "/home/gbuday/prooftheory/polyml/bin/poly"
"Program to run as Standard SML read-eval-print loop."
:type 'string)
```

which indeed starts PolyML, the version I want to use.

When I type `M-x run-sml` to run an inferior SML read-eval-print loop I get

```
Cannot open load file: sml-proc
```

in the minibuffer. What should I do better here?

Comment: Install sml-mode via `M-x package-list-packages RET`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `sml-proc` file I'm aware of.  What version of `sml-mode` are you using, it looks like the current is 6.7, and autoloading `run-sml` (or `sml-run`) should be done from `sml-mode` as well, eg

```
(autoload 'run-sml "sml-mode")
```

You should set the sml program with `(setq sml-program-name ...)` in your config file, you don't need to change the source code.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/smlnj/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/smlnj/bin"  exec-path))
```

replacing /usr/local with the appropriate path.